# Callback is not a function?

Tags: javascript, callback

I know this has been asked hundreds of times, however I've written loads of callback functions before and I think I've just gone a bit blind to my problem/

I have a function:

```
function firstSend(){
    client.write(Buffer.from([0x5C,0x57,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x2F]));

    check(function(msg){
        if(msg == true){
            console.log("Lets go");
        }
    });
}
```

That calls the function `check` with a callback

The check function returns true when it is complete:

```
function check(callback) {
    let m;
    if(message != null) m = message.trim();

    if(m != "OK"){
        setTimeout(check, 1000);
        return;
    }
    return callback(true);
}
```

Everything works correctly until it tries to do a callback, at which point it tells me its not a function.

I've logged callback out and it logs as a function, so i'm a little stumped

Comment: The internals of `setTimeout` don't know what you want to pass to `check`, so it passes nothing. You can solve this by passing a function that closes over `callback` and calls `check` with that argument. `setTimeout(() => check(callback), 1000)`

Comment: Another solution is to pass `callback` as a separate argument to `setTimeout`, which informs `setTimeout` that you want it forwarded on to `check` when invoked. `setTimeout(check, 1000, callback)`. It is variadic, and so as many extra args that get set to `setTimeout` will get sent to your function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not passing the `callback` in `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function () {
    check(callback)
}, 1000);
```

instead of

```
setTimeout(check, 1000);
```

OR, Alternatively you can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
setTimeout(check.bind(null, callback), 1000);.
```

Comment: Alternatively: `check.bind(null, callback)`.

Comment: Ah bloody hell.  Completely missed that.  Thanks! `setTimeout(() => {check(callback)}, 1000);`